# How to update a DataGridView

Tags: datagridview

I have the following

IQueryable objs = 'some linq-to-entity query';

dataGridView1.DataSource = objs;

Which works fine. After the data is updated I need to refresh the dataGridView; I can't find anyway to refresh the grid, I have tried ReFresh(), Invalidate(). Looked at many questions/posts on this site and others but nothing happens.

Does anyone know a way to update a DataGridView?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You will have to assign the datasource again.
Once you know your data is updated,

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = objs;
```